# Within Python, what is exactly a sequence of strings? (or else Glib bug?)

Tags: python, python-2.7, glib

I know the question may looks stupid, but I am really not able to figure it out. I naively though a sequence of strings is a list of strings. However, this fails:

```
(pid, stdin, stdout, stderr) = glib.spawn_async(
    argv=["foo", "bar"],
    envp=None,
    flags=glib.SPAWN_SEARCH_PATH + glib.SPAWN_CHILD_INHERITS_STDIN,
    standard_input=True,
    standard_output=True,
    standard_error=True)
```

Fails with this error:

```
TypeError: glib.spawn_async: first argument must be a sequence of strings
```

I tried with a tuple, which gives nothing better.

What is a sequence of strings if not a list? I though about a possible Python‑Glib bug, while I don't believe such a bug can really exists. I found mention of a similar message on the web, but I don't know if this is this error which is a bug, or the occurrence of this error which is one.

-- edit --

Using this even shorter sample, ends into the same:

```
(pid, stdin, stdout, stderr) = glib.spawn_async(argv=["foo", "bar"])
```

As requested by posters, here is the full trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<...>/test.py", line 92, in <module>
    run()
  File "<...>/test.py", line 62, in run
    standard_error=True)
TypeError: glib.spawn_async: first argument must be a sequence of strings
```

Comment: hmm interesting... are you 100% sure it's that very line? a list of strings is definitely a sequence of strings

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: When I paste your code sample in, I get: `TypeError: glib.spawn_async: second argument must be a sequence of strings`, which is similar to your error and yet different in an important aspect. Are you sure yours doesn't say `second`?

Comment: Odd. According to the [documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/glib-functions.html#function-glib--spawn-async) I found, `envp=None` is a valid second argument. What version are you on?

Comment: @user2357112 and @kwatford: reducing the sample to the even shorter `(pid, stdin, stdout, stderr) = glib.spawn_async(argv=["foo", "bar"])` gives the same result. I'm running Python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Could you copy/paste the full traceback into your question?

Comment: @user2357112, here is, I've just updated the initial message.

Comment: Huh.  Your shorter example gives me `GError: Failed to execute child process "foo" (No such file or directory)`, which is what I'd expect.  Very strangely, though, adding `envp=None` -- which is what the docs say the default value is -- gives `TypeError: glib.spawn_async: second argument must be a sequence of strings`, but `envp=[]` works (i.e. gives the expected error).  I'm not sure that `envp` is being treated according to spec.

Comment: Could you paste in the results of `glib.glib_version` and `glib.pyglib_version`? I'm on `(2, 32, 4)` and `(2, 28, 6)`, for reference.

Comment: @kwatford, it says: (2, 32, 4) and (2, 28, 6). Do you believe it's a bug? Seems nobody believe I'm wrong to believe a sequence of strings is indeed a list of strings.

Comment: @user2357112, talking about the documentation, I also noticed something else. The documentation says the `working_directory` parameter may be `None`, but I also get an error on this, claiming it must be a string. That's the reason why this parameter does not appears in the sample I posted.

Comment: We're using the same OS, version of python, and glib/pyglib version. I'm sort of at a loss. You didn't somehow accidentally start using Python 3 here, did you?

Comment: @kwatford, I'm using Python 2.7, however I have the so called future line at the start of each Python file, `from __future__ import (absolute_import, print_function, unicode_literals)`. I removed it, and indeed, now it behave differently. I don't know how this can be. I will answer my own question with this note.

Comment: Hem, no finally, that do not really answer my question, there remains an exact same error, except now it's with the second argument, the same you noticed in comment #3. This more and more looks like a bug. Where should I submit this bug report?

Comment: @Hibou57 Aha, yes, the `unicode_literals` would cause your first problem. They're not strings, not in the sense that glib expects. If you want to use `unicode_literals`, prefix those strings with `b`. So `b"foo"` indicates a byte string instead of a unicode string. For `envp`, simply don't provide that keyword. Let's see what error you get next.

Comment: @kwatford, yes, indeed, using `b` to tell it's legacy 8 bits characters solved the issue. I'm still surprised about `envp` and `working_directory` not handled as documented, but that should be for another question. Thanks a lot for you pointer! Without you, I would not have try to follow this track. Feel free to add this answer if you wish, sure I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments on the question:

1. The strings shouldn't be unicode objects. If you have have Python 3 or `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, make byte literals via the `b"foo"` syntax.
2. The `envp` argument seems to have diverged from its documentation. Don't provide None to it. Just don't provide that keyword/position if you aren't going to use it.

Comment: And the hint about Unicode strings, applies to all Glib functions, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: You might be able to use unicode in some places, but it may require that you encode it into whatever encoding glib/gobject/whatever is expecting (via `foo.encode('utf-8')` or similar). I don't know enough about those libraries to tell you about their unicode support.