# How to fix TypeError: glib.spawn_async with Kupfer (python)?

Tags: python, linux, unicode, glib, app-launcher

Whenever I try to pass an argument to Kupfer I am getting an error (debug run) that says that "TypeError: glib.spawn_async: second argument must be a sequence of strings". I have no idea why that is the case. I am just trying to pass some  arguments using the text mode to a bash script ("command $*")  or any other executable but this error making it impossible to use Kupfer for such purposes :(

This app is not maintained much. My Python knowledge of unicode and similar issues is very limited. I would like to either fix this issue or if this is not a bug find the right way to use that feature.

How can I address this issue in the code? I want to patch it so I can us it.

github page
https://github.com/engla/kupfer

error messgae
http://pastebin.com/rUJDnetL

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/kupfer/kupfer/ui/browser.py", line 1615, in _activate
    self.data_controller.activate(ui_ctx=self._make_gui_ctx())
  File "/usr/share/kupfer/kupfer/core/data.py", line 800, in activate
    res, ret = ctx.run(leaf, action, sobject, ui_ctx=ui_ctx)
  File "/usr/share/kupfer/kupfer/core/commandexec.py", line 303, in run
    ret = activate_action(execution_token, obj, action, iobj)
  File "/usr/share/kupfer/kupfer/core/commandexec.py", line 80, in activate_action
    return _activate_action_single(obj, action, iobj, kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/kupfer/kupfer/core/commandexec.py", line 86, in _activate_action_single
    ret = action.activate(obj, iobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/kupfer/kupfer/plugin/commands.py", line 131, in activate
    utils.AsyncCommand(argv, finish_callback, None, stdin=leaf.object)
  File "/usr/share/kupfer/kupfer/utils.py", line 126, in __init__
    standard_error=True, flags=flags, envp=env)
TypeError: glib.spawn_async: second argument must be a sequence of strings
```

Comment: Add some code into the `__init__` function to print argv right before glib.spawn_async is called on it. It's supposed to be a list of `str` objects, if its not, you know what the issue is. Then you just need to work backwards to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Note that this requires a sequence of bytestrings, not Unicode.

Comment: Further discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792231/within-python-what-is-exactly-a-sequence-of-strings-or-else-glib-bug

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know I'm super late to answer this question but I just ran into the same problem kupfer is such an awesome utility that I couldn't accept having a bug like that in it.

Anyway, change the call to glib.spawn_async (kupfer/utils.py:125-126) from this:
`glib.spawn_async(argv, standard_output=True, standard_input=True,
                      standard_error=True, flags=flags, envp=env)`
to simply this:
`glib.spawn_async(argv)`

That worked for me and hopefully others too :)

P.S. If anyone is still using kupfer and is coming to this answer, I just forked the repo and want to try to revive/maintain it so feel free to pitch in if you're interested [kupfer2](https://github.com/logileifs/kupfer)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [glib doc](https://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html#function-glib--spawn-async), the error message does not address `argv` which is the *first* argument, but the second, `envp`. The bug was also raised on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/kupfer/+bug/1318762) and a fix has been provided by [KarolBedkowski](https://github.com/KarolBedkowski/kupfer-adds/commit/ac04b898e0d9f8061daacf83d1770061e3e3d5f6).